# AIC scores the same

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, model-selection, aic

I am creating a series of linear mixed models using lmer (package lme4 in R) followed with model selection using AIC. The models are interactive with 6 explanatory variables (5 factors, 1 continuous variable).
The piece I cannot figure out is when I run the AIC() function to include all of my models for model selection, every AIC score is the exact same value.
I'm happy to share code if needed but am wondering if there is something obvious I am missing here.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your model prone to overfitting? IOW: do you have few data compared to the number of time stamps and variables? In such a situation, many models will yield an excellent fit. Remeber that AIC is an in sample criterion, ie. the model is evaluted on the same data with which it was trained.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the conditional AIC (cAIC4 package). It even has a neat function: anocAIC(model1, model2, ....) that compares all models. The conditional AIC is better suited and more appropiate for lmer and glmer models (can give references if need be). Be aware that it is also sometimes, although rarely, gives the same number for 2 or more different models. I usually run my models (mostly lmer) with REML=FALSE (again, can give references for this), then diagnose and select with cAIC, performance package and graphically (for example check_model within performance package). For code example see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70774407/17973152